# How to Render Composite layers for timeline video creation

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, timeline

Hi and thanks in advance!

I followed the tut to make a planet using Blender 2.8.1.16, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUNfPavsViY which resulted in an image containing 2 layers, Planet and Atmosphere.  I can render each separately using cycles and see them in the compositor.  I can create a simple timeline to spin the planet 360 degrees on Z and play it in timeline.  But when I attempt to render a series of images from the timeline, it ONLY renders the frame playhead images.

How can I instruct blender to create all of the images needed for the timeline rotation?

In Output I have, Frame Start=1, End=250, Step=1, In Post Processing  I have tried with Compositing on and off and I have Sequencer Checked.

Comment: Okay from what I understand you are confused why it's rendering the images at where the playhead is right ?

Comment: Yes, when I did the Donut I believe I simply set up a a timeline with some keyframes and it rendered the entire set of frames that I could then render as a video.  Is there a different behavior for Compositor or having View Layers that I am missing or am I just confused about some simple thing that I am not understanding?

Comment: I think you have everything

Comment: I must be missing something, when I render I get whatever frame the playhead is on and just that one but when I did this before I rendered all frames within the start and end and was able to render a video from an image sequence.  In this case I never get an image sequence.  You said that I am 'confused why it's rendering the images (you wrote plural) at where the playhead is" - I would say NO, I am confused why it ONLY renders the single image at the playhead and not all of the images defined by Frame Start and Frame End.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Peasy - I was trying to use Render Image to render my animation sequence, not render animation.  After doing another project I realized I need to render animation either as a series of images (preferred) or as a single video output.  I was thinking that Render Animation was not for the image sequence but for the movie output.  Now I see that is part of the output format for Render Animation. ;-)

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct.